# Prove that for any $x,y,z \ge 0$ , we have $\sqrt[3]{xyz} \le \frac{x+y+z}{3}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

Prove that for any $x,y,z \ge 0$ $$\sqrt[3]{xyz} \le \frac{x+y+z}{3}$$
I've done it with four variables, but my textbook is asking me to do it with three and I'm not sure where to start. It also says to use the four variable method, but have $w=(xyz)^\frac{1}{3}$ which confuses me further.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of you've done with four variables, you can use it like this.

$$x+y+z + \frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq 4\sqrt[4]{xyz(\frac{x+y+z}{3})}$$

then $$\frac{4}{3}(x+y+z) \geq 4\sqrt[4]{xyz(\frac{x+y+z}{3})}$$

or, $$\frac{x+y+z}{3} \geq \sqrt[4]{xyz(\frac{x+y+z}{3})},$$

$$\left(\frac{x+y+z}{3}\right)^3 \geq xyz.$$

Answer (score 1):

With $w = (xyz)^{1/3}$, applying AM GM inequality for four variables, we have 
$$\frac{x+y+z+w}{4} \geq (xyz(xyz)^{1/3})^{1/4} = (xyz)^{1/3}$$
The required inequality follows.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use the factorisation 
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\equiv (a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ca)\ .$$
If you can prove that the expression is always non-negative when $a,b,c\geq 0$, then you're done. This boils down to showing 
$$a^2+b^2+c^2\geq ab+bc+ca\ ,$$ 
which shouldn't be too tricky.