# Proving that $\sqrt[3]{xyz} ≤ \frac{x+y+z}{3}$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing

I was able to prove the AGM inequality for four variables, however when asked to prove it for 3 I don't understand how to correctly do it.

$\sqrt[3]{xyz} ≤ \frac{x+y+z}{3}$

But I'm supposed to solve it using the AGM inequality for four variables, with $w = \sqrt[3]{xyz}$

Step by step would be really helpful.

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: See here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2435537/proving-the-agm-inequality-with-3-variables

Comment: $\sqrt[4]{xyzw} ≤ \frac{x+y+z+w}{4}$ sub in $w = \sqrt[3]{xyz}$, $\sqrt[4]{xyz(\sqrt[3]{xyz})} ≤ \frac{x+y+z+(\sqrt[3]{xyz})}{4}$ and now I'm stuck.

Comment: Let $3w=x+y+z$ and then $w=(x+y+z+w) /4\geq \sqrt[4]{xyzw}$ or $w\geq \sqrt[3]{xyz}$ and we are done.